# How to know rows are part of same time window for TWCS in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra and particularly for TWCS. Is there any way, I can query rows which are from same time window as per the TWCS in cassandra or is there any query or method by which I can know, rows are from the same window.
I need this to generate matrix for each time window for TWCS.